# Results View = The type

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, linq-to-sql, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight 4 ria services and sql server 2008,

we are using a stored procedure to return some data which we are displaying in a datagrid, when issummary =0
we are using the same stored procedure to return the summary of the data, when issummary =1

when the issummary =0 the stored procedure is returning the data,but when issummary =1, it is trowing an error saying

```
Results View = The type 'VSO.Models.Server.PFO' exists in both 'VSO.Web.dll' and 'DataContractSurrogates_451c5697-49be-4ec5-9d42-89486ff684a6'
```

in the designer.cs file.

and also a cast exception in the domainservice.cs file

Specified cast is not valid.

expanded:

```
  at System.Data.DataTableReader.GetGuid(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Rereader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at Read_PFO(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at VSO.DomainServices.Server.PFODomainService.PFOSelectByStores(String storeIds, Int32 filter, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Guid userId, String sortColumn, String productIDs, Boolean isSummary, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Hood_VSO\.VSO\.VSO.Web\Services\PFODomainService.cs:line 820
```

where am i going wrong, can anyone please help me out with this, thank you very much

Comment: The error you report it's usually reported by the debugger due to the way wcf ria services deals with DataContract, is the error raised by the debugger or the webserver itself ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, 
the no. of columns returned by the stored procedure when summary is 0  are greater than the no. of columns returned by the stored procedure when summary is 1, and also those columns are nullable.

so it is trowing a cast exception.

I created a new stored procedure for summary =1. with the requirements.